# Are these rings a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I want to check if the following rings are fiels:

1. $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 5\rangle$
2. $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$
3. $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^4+2\rangle$

For the first one I have found the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/5\times \mathbb{Z}/5$ with kernel $(5)\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$.

We conclude that this is not a field/, or not?

Comment: Hint: Can you find two perfect squares in $\mathbb{Z}$ whose sum is $5$?  Alternatively, your codomain has zero divisors.  Find their preimages.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you mean sum, not difference, right?

Comment: @user10354138, Yes, I do, thanks.

Comment: We have that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+1)$ and since $x^2+1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ the ring is not a field. Is that correct? @MichaelBurr

Comment: And the same holds also at the last one? $x^4+2$ is not irreducible in $F_3$ and so the ring is not a field? @MichaelBurr

Comment: It is indeed correct – even obvious in the last case, since  in $\mathbf F_3$, $x^4+2$ is the same as $x^4-1$.

Comment: What is your ring homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}/5\times\mathbb{Z}/5$?  The standard multiplication for a product ring makes the map challenging to describe.